# Calendar Plugins - Featured Widget

Tags: plugins, widgets, calendar, the-events-calendar

I was curious to know if anyone had ever used a calendar plugin with the ability to produce a "featured event" widget like the one below (except this is in Drupal, of which I'm thinking about moving this site to Wordpress) where it provides the date, time, title and uses the featured image. Is this at all possible? I'm looking through widgets now, but figured I would ask and see if anyone has ever come across this before.

Thanks!

[image]